# Is there a way to declare php.ini open_basedir no value to htaccess file?

Tags: php

The php script I'm trying to install detected that open_basedir has a value on php.ini but my hosting is not allowing me to edit the php.ini so I'm trying to do it on my domains .htaccess using

```
php_value open_basedir
```

but i don't know what value to set in htaccess to remove the default value detected by the php script. I tried adding none or novalue but no luck. Any help please.

Comment: Try the syntax shown here, http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir: `php_admin_value open_basedir none`

Comment: @misorude tried that but no luck

Comment: Does your hoster allow you to modify PHP settings via .htaccess at all? Do they even have PHP running as an Apache module? (Only then can you use .htaccess to configure it, if PHP is running using something else like FastCGI, this isn’t supposed to work in the first place.)

Comment: I guest because this values are already in htaccess by default: php_value display_errors Off, php_flag magic_quotes 1, php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 1, php_value mbstring.http_input auto, php_value date.timezone Asia/Manila and yes, the server is using Apache module.

Comment: in PHP 5.3+ `open_basedir` is changeable via `PHP_INI_ALL`. So `php_value` should work fine if Apache is serving php scripts with the `mod_php` module. However there may be a delay from applying the setting in the .htaccess file and when it is processed, depending on the worker used to load php. To see the changes immediately you would need to restart the Apache service. If using `CGI\FastCGI`, you can try using [`PHP .user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) If you are using `php-fpm` you can set the values in the FPM pool configuration.

Comment: It should also be noted that you can not use `php_admin_value` in the .htaccess file and if `php_admin_value open_basedir` is set in your hosts apache base config or virtual host config files, it **can not** be overridden in your .htaccess using `php_value` or by using `ini_set` See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php for more details. To determine if it is enforced, check `ini_set('open_basedir', 'none'); phpinfo();`, if the setting is not updated in phpinfo result, `php_admin_value open_basedir` was set in the host config files.